# What should I do with the verification token after user registration?

Tags: java, database, jvm

I have completed registration and login of users on my site. After registering the user in the system, a token (UUID) is created which is saved in the database together with the user ID and the expiration date of the token. The user receives a link with a token and after clicking on this URL​ the account is activated.

Question: what should I do with these tokens in the database? Should the token after user activation be removed from the database or marked as used etc.?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what can be done with the token after it has served its initial purpose (activating the account). Is there any risk if a user attempts to activate their account twice? Or can the password be reset using the token?

If the token is harmless after use, its probably fine to leave it in the database. If you expect to have many users and want to conserve space in your DB, you could clean up the tokens from the DB after they have been used.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but your setup is pretty okay you probably only replace that token with a new one every time the user resets their password given the account is now active.